# Using libTooling to parse vector of paths

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to feed in `CommonOptionsParser` a list of file paths, instead of `argv` directly. I want to first pass `argv` to a function I have designed that handles the path and returns a vector of strings containing the absolute path of all CPP files I want clang to parse. Is this something doable since `CommonOptionsParser` seems to really only accept `argv` and `argc`.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
void getFuncDecls(vector<string> &files, vector<string> &functionDecls) {
    CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(?????, files, FAICCategory);
    ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(), OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());

    FP::MyPrinter Printer;
    MatchFinder Finder;

    StatementMatcher functionMatcher = callExpr(callee(functionDecl())).bind("functions");

    Finder.addMatcher(functionMatcher, &Printer);

    Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());
}
```

Thank you,
tiferrei

Comment: Unclear what you ask. When an interface expects char*[] and int then you have to pass those. If you have something else available then you have to convert what you have into char*[] and int.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I have tried that before but I seem to be stuck converting the string vector into `const char **`. How can I do this? I'm sorry if this is a beginner question but I have tried pretty much all of the similar conversion questions on SO and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: This website made a better job at answering my question: http://web.archive.org/web/20120308055708/http://bbgen.net:80/blog/2011/06/string-to-argc-argv/